# Когда нужно использовать htmlspecialcharts

Tags: php, взлом

Проблема в том что я до сих пор не понимаю как можно взломать сайт на php.
Например есть переменная, которую я получаю через GET. Стоит ли преобразовывать в ней символы, если я просто её сравниваю? А если вывожу где то?

Comment: ВСЕГДА чистите ВСЕ данные получаемые от ненадежных источников (включая пользователей)

Answer (score 4):

Пример.
Чат. Сообщения пользователей не обрабатываются никаким образом. Один из хацкеров отправляет вместо обычного сообщения JS:

```
<script>
  window.location = "http://hashcode.ru/questions/245199/";
</script>
```

В таком же виде сообщение выводиться в чат. Скрипт срабатывает и перенаправляет всех пользователей на страницу злоумышленника.

Answer (score 1):

Например, для показа сообщения, введенного пользователем, которое может содержать нежелательное форматирование. Существует также  htmlentities().

Answer (score 0):

Сайты взламывают обычно через XSS уязвимости, т.е. когда пользователь ввел в поле например следующий текст:

```
<script>alert('123');</script>
```

то после обновления страницы, если этот код не будет пропущен сайтом через htmlspecialchars, то этот код просто напросто выполнится, и пользователи, которые будут попадать на эту страницу, будут видеть сообщение '123' по центру экрана. А если этот код был пропущен через функцию htmlspecialchars, то такие символы как "< > &" и другие, будут преобразованы в &lt; &gt; &amp; ([см. тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)), т.е. при подстановке в основной код этого фрагмента - он не будет исполняемым уже, так как < > будут трактоваться как символы, а не как html код (который нужно выполнить).
Если на сайте есть уязвимость, то вместо выше указанного кода вставляют уже либо скрытый iframe размером 1x1, ему указывают какую-то ссылку на тот же пхп скрипт (Ваш), который будет вызываться при попадании пользователей на страницу с этой уязвимостью, и который сможет передавать некоторые данные вашему скрипту с этого сайта (обычно это куки пользователей).